# Difference between electrostatic pressure and mechanical pressure exerted by electric field

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, pressure

I have a hollow cylinder of a known surface density and a known fracture stress. We can easily calculate the field component normal to the surface and get the pressure by dividing by surface. Alternatively we can use the electrostatic pressure formula.
I don't think these two match, and this is not the first problem I've encountered with the same dilemma. What is the difference between these two? Which one should be used to calculate the stress?

Answer (score 1):

Inside a conductors system there are mechanical forces due both to interactions between charges of the same conductor and interactions between charges of different conductors.

Consider a single conductor. At electrostatic equilibrium $\rho_{inside}=0$, $\vec{E}_{inside}=0$, but charges goes on the surface of the conductor and this gives a $\sigma\ne0$ on the conductor surface. The surface of the conductor is a insurmountable barrier for the charged particles and the mutual repulsion forces between these charges is traslated in an electrostatic pressure. Let's try to calculate this electrostatic pressure with a mechanical approach and we will prove that the result is the same as the formula that is usually given for electrostatic pressure.

Let us give a conductor surface $S$ and divide it in $dS$ and $S-dS$. [image]

The electric field near the conductor is:
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}_0=\vec{E}_0^{(dS)}+\vec{E}_0^{(S-dS)}
\end{equation}
and so
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}_0^{(S-dS)}=\vec{E}_0-\vec{E}_0^{(dS)}
\end{equation}
For the Coulomb theorem the field $\vec{E}_0$ is given by (see previous figure):
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}_{0e}=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0} \hat{n}\\
\vec{E}_{0i}=0
\end{equation}
The field $\vec{E}_0^{(dS)}$ very close to the surface $dS$ can be calculate as the field generated by an infinite plane charged $\sigma$ at that point. In this way:
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}_{0e}^{(dS)}=\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0} \hat{n}\\
\vec{E}_{0i}^{(dS)}=-\frac{\sigma}{2\epsilon_0} \hat{n}
\end{equation}
[image]

Combining these results we find:
\begin{equation}
\vec{E}_{0e}^{(S-dS)}=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0} \hat{n}\\
\vec{E}_{0i}^{(S-dS)}=\frac{\sigma}{\epsilon_0} \hat{n}
\end{equation}
[image]

Now, let's calculate the electrostatic force $\vec{F}^{(dS)}$ exerted on the surface $dS$ by the field $\vec{E}_0^{(S-dS)}$ with the usual definition of the electric force on a charge:
\begin{equation}
\vec{F}^{(dS)}=(\sigma dS)(\vec{E}_0^{(S-dS)})\to\\
\to\vec{F}^{(dS)}=\frac{\sigma^2}{2\epsilon_0}\hat{n}dS\to\\
\to\vec{F}_{tot}=\int_S \frac{\sigma^2}{2\epsilon_0}\hat{n}dS
\end{equation}
What is the integrand? A force per unit area that (in mechanics) we call pressure:
\begin{equation}
p=\frac{\sigma^2}{2\epsilon_0}
\end{equation}
and this is what we call electrostatic pressure. Note that it behaves as "an inverse" pressure in the sense that point by point on the conductor the force is directed outward and not inward and it pushes the surface of the conductor outward, that is it tends to make it expand.

This is an intuitive and "mechanical" way to find the expression of electrostatic pressure on a conductor. There are other two ways that I know to find the same result: (1) with energetic consideration and virtual work and (2) more generally with the use of the electrical stress tensor:
\begin{equation}
T_{ij}=\epsilon_0 E_iE_j-\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_0 E^2\delta_{ij}
\end{equation}

For (2) you can see on Modern Electrodynamics by A. Zangwill.

I studied the (1) on an italian book called "Fisica 2. Elettromagnetismo-ottica" by C. Mencuccini, V. Silvestrini (maybe you can find something similar on Griffiths).

-Figures taken from "Fisica 2. Elettromagnetismo-ottica" by C. Mencuccini, V. Silvestrini.